# Extracting Arabic number from a text file

Tags: python, regex, string, ocr

I have a text file that includes   ")رقم : ٤٢٢٧ ٢٢٤" . I am using this code to extract ٢٢٤٤٢٢٧  :

```
 arabic_num = re.search(r':([\d\s]+)', text, re.UNICODE)
    arabic_num = arabic_num.group(1)
    arabic_num = arabic_num.replace(' ', '')
```

But the output is wrong `٤٢٢٧٢٢٤`. This happens when I remove the space between `٢٢٤` and `٤٢٢٧`. How Can I fix it, keeping in mind that any arabic digits can be between `:` and `)` and sometimes the number in the text file doesn't include a space(s) between its digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will capture everything between the ")" and ":"

```
text = ")رقم : ٤٢٢٧ ٢٢٤"
arabic_num = re.search(r'\).*\:', text, re.UNICODE)
```

and if you don't want the ")", ":", and space you can strip:

```
arabic_num.group().strip(")").strip(":").replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the output to be ٢٢٤٤٢٢٧ not ٢٢٤ ٤٢٢٧ . Please note the text variable in your code is not the string in the question.

Comment: Updated to the correct string, but the concept is similar. You can add the `.replace(' ', '')` to remove the spaces